# Write permission denied when writing to logs using Django NonRel

Tags: python, django

new to web dev here. I'm trying to run a really basic web application using the djangoappengine fork of django nonrel 1.6.  I'm running it locally, but the logging doesn't work.  Here's the error:

```
python manage.py runserver
INFO     2015-07-07 18:22:18,926 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2015-07-07 18:22:19,157 sdk_update_checker.py:257] The SDK is up to date.
INFO     2015-07-07 18:22:19,218 api_server.py:204] Starting API server at: http://localhost:51763
INFO     2015-07-07 18:22:19,225 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://127.0.0.1:8080
INFO     2015-07-07 18:22:19,226 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2015-07-07 18:22:22,080 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
    __import__(cumulative_path)
  File "/Users/prog/Desktop/djangoNonRel/project2/djangoappengine/main/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    setup_env(settings.DEV_APPSERVER_VERSION)
  File "/Users/prog/Desktop/djangoNonRel/project2/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/prog/Desktop/djangoNonRel/project2/django/conf/__init__.py", line 50, in _setup
    self._configure_logging()
  File "/Users/prog/Desktop/djangoNonRel/project2/django/conf/__init__.py", line 80, in _configure_logging
    logging_config_func(self.LOGGING)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 576, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/Users/prog/Documents/guestbook.log'
INFO     2015-07-07 18:22:22,086 module.py:812] default: "GET /_ah/warmup HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

The server continues to run, but as you can see, I can't write to the log that is being generated. I've tried these fixes so far:
-used chmod 755 and 777 to change the permissions on the full path
-changed the path to the current one(old one was creating the log in my project folder)
-used chmod 755 and 777 to change the permissions on the new full path

Here's my setting.py code:

```
# Django settings for myapp project.

# Initialize App Engine and import the default settings (DB backend, etc.).
# If you want to use a different backend you have to remove all occurences
# of "djangoappengine" from this file.
from djangoappengine.settings_base import *
import os

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

# Activate django-dbindexer for the default database
DATABASES['default'] = {'ENGINE': 'dbindexer', 'TARGET': DATABASES['default']}

AUTOLOAD_SITECONF = 'indexes'

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = False

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'media')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'ilpeey9j&dk@4u5gx!iv)0hnxm*eu=nfpmvn92!n)+mc3#q0t5'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # This loads the index definitions, so it has to come first
    'autoload.middleware.AutoloadMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.request'
)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/guestbook/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/Users/prog/Desktop/djangoNonRel/project2/templates/guestbook/',
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'djangotoolbox',
    'autoload',
    'dbindexer',
    'guestbook',

    # djangoappengine should come last, so it can override a few manage.py commands
    'djangoappengine',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/Users/prog/Documents/guestbook.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'guestbook': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need anything else from me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix permissions with the chmod command
try this command:

```
chmod 775 /Users/prog/Documents/guestbook.log
```

Comment: I tried that, got the same error as before. None of the variations for chmod seem to work. I've tried, 755, 775, and 777